# Get-Eventlog group by Event and Day

Tags: powershell, get-eventlog

```
Get-EventLog -Logname system -Source "Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy" -EntryType "Information"| group-object -property source | sort-object -property Time -descending
```

It does group everything together and counts it but I want the count to be also by day.

Results be like:

```
02.10.2015 10 Microsoft-Windows......
04.11.2016 2  Microsoft-Windows.....
08.11.2016 13 Microsoft-Windows......
```

and so on.

How can I get the date splitting in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by two different properties and we can fabricate a property to hold the day as a string.

```
Get-EventLog -Logname system -Source "Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy" -EntryType "Information" |
    Add-Member Day -MemberType ScriptProperty -Value { $this.TimeGenerated.ToString('dd.MM.yyyy') } -PassThru |
    Group-Object 'Day', 'Source'
```

Comment: Wow great just what I needed, now I just need to understand what you did there :-)

Comment: For each of the events we're adding a new calculated property which will hold the date as a formatted string. It groups everything by the calculated property Day first then by event source. `$this` is a special variable used to access the thing we added the property to, so the little script block is specific to each event.